# Deploying Symfony2 with Capistrano3 - permissions

Tags: symfony, deployment, capistrano3

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony2 based site with capistrano/symfony, and I've already gotten it to properly run the 'composer install'. However, it runs that as the deployment user.

When the website runs, it can't write any more cache files as the webuser, as the permissions don't appear to set the permissions on the cache and log directories recursively.

The cap3 plugin capistrano-file-permissions are set as `set :file_permissions_paths, ["app/logs", "app/cache"]`

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible solution is to use ACLs, if available. You can read more in symfony documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#book-installation-permissions